# Understand Chinese phrase

Tags: translation

I have recently rewatched the Jackie Chan film 'Little Big Soldier' and loved the phrase he says often, translated in English as 'how marvelous'. I want to know the words he says  as translations of 'how marvelous' using Google translate do not match. I would love it if anyone was able to provide the Chinese symbols and phonetic language version (forgive my ignorance).

The phrase is said here twice at 1:04:20 in the film in this YouTube video. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=DzDdgjqj7vg

To me it sounds like ti haldur. Although it obviously isn't anything like that in reality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 挺好的，挺好的。
> tǐng hǎo de, tǐng hǎo de.
> Not bad, not bad.

Note: because of tone sandhi of consecutive third tones, the first syllable is pronounced in the second tone instead of the third:

> tíng hǎo de, tíng hǎo de.

Comment: Thank you very much, is it a common phrase?

Comment: Fairly common I would say.